# PHP compilation Error *** [libphp5.la] Error 1

Tags: php

Dear All,
                I have a problem in compilation of PHP server PHP version 5.5.14.
                the configuration of server are mention below.

1. Red hat enterprise linux 64 bit
2. Apache server 2.4.9
3. openssl 1.0.1 h
   i have successfuly installed the Apache server is working fine but when i want to compile PHP with open ssl is show the below error message.

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a(rsa_crpt.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `a local symbol' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libphp5.la] Error 1

but when i compile php with out openssl is working fine

any suggestions to resolve this problem

thanks in advance
 Fasih

Comment: Did you recompile libcrypto using -fPIC as it says in the message?

Comment: no i did not recompile with libcrypto using -fPIC can you tell me the method how to recomplie it?